# Find $ 1\cdot 3^0 +3\cdot 3^1 +5\cdot 3^2 +\cdots +(2n+1)3^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I denoted $ 1\cdot 3^0 +3\cdot 3^1 +5\cdot 3^2 +\cdots +(2n+1)3^n $ with $P$.

- $n=0 : P=1$
- $n=1 : P=1+9=10$
- $n=2 : P=10+45=55$
- $n=3 : P=55+189=244$
- $n=4 : P=244+729=973$
- $n=5 : P=973+2673=3646$

I can't see a pattern.

Then I found $3P$. Then I subtracted $P$ from $3P$, i.e. $3P-P$ and still I couldn't get a correct formula. How can I find a formula for the sum of this sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $P=1\times 1+3\times 3+5\times 3^2+...+(2n+1)\times 3^n$.

Then $3P=1\times 3+3\times 3^2+5\times 3^3+...+(2n+1)\times 3^{n+1}$.

Now $3P-P=(2n+1)\times 3^{n+1}-1-2\times (3+3^2+...+3^n)$.

Since the last term on the right side of the last equation is a geometric series, we have the answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(2k+1)3^k = 2\sum_{k=0}^nk3^k + \sum_{k=0}^n3^k 
$$
now this guy
$$
\sum_{k=0}^nk3^k  
$$
can be reduced to a recognisable form by noticing
$$
\frac{d}{da}a^k = ka^{k-1}\implies a\frac{d}{da}a^k = ka^k
$$
so taking the sum of both sides and permuting the derivative and sum we get
$$
a\frac{d}{da}\sum_{k=0}^na^k = \sum_{k=0}^nka^k
$$
can you take it from here?

Comment: Easier if you write it as $2\sum (k+1)3^k - \sum 3^k$. Then don't have that extra $a$ to deal with.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that is a neater way indeed :).

Answer (score 1):

More generally, consider $f_n(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n (2j+1) x^j$, so your case is 
$f_n(3)$.  You should know the geometric series
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n x^j = \dfrac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x - 1}\ (\text{for}\ x \ne 1)$$ 
Now
$$\eqalign{\sum_{j=0}^n j x^j &= \sum_{j=0}^n x \dfrac{d}{dx} x^j \cr
&= x \dfrac{d}{dx} \sum_{j=0}^n x^j\cr&= x \dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\cr
&= \dfrac{(n+1) x^{n+1}}{x-1} - \dfrac{x^{n+2}-x}{(x-1)^2}}$$
Then $$ f_n(x) = 2 \sum_{j=0}^n j x^j +  \sum_{j=0}^n x^j$$
Set $x = 3$ and simplify...

Comment: Oops, somehow got the problem slightly wrong.  Will edit.